# Can't add combobox to TabelView JavaFx

Tags: javafx, combobox, tableview

I am new with javafx. I want to add to tableview column a combobox, which takes options from object's ArrayList (items can be different accordong to the objects). Everything fine with another column (there are just string values). I tried to find the solution, but nothing works. Instead of combobox array of ArrayList displays. 
[image]

There code of class below is not a real code - for simplicity. Data will be got from database.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import ru.content_analysis.data_classes.FullWorkProject;

/**
 *for table of adding the texts - choosing variable vals before adding the text
 * @author aryumin
 */
public class VarAndValuesForTable {
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty varId;
    private final SimpleStringProperty varName;
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<ArrayList<String>> varValues;

    public VarAndValuesForTable(int varId, String varName, ArrayList<String> varValues){
        this.varId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(varId);
        this.varName = new SimpleStringProperty(varName);
        this.varValues = new SimpleObjectProperty(varValues);
    }

    public int getVarId(){
        return this.varId.get();
    }

    public void setVarId(int varId){
        this.varId.set(varId);
    }

    public String getVarName(){
        return this.varName.get();
    }

    public void setVarName(String varName){
        this.varName.set(varName);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getVarValues(){
        return this.varValues.get();
    }

    public void setVarValues(ArrayList<String> varValues){
        this.varValues.set(varValues);
    }





    public static ArrayList<VarAndValuesForTable> getAllVarsNamesWithValues(FullWorkProject prj){
        ArrayList<VarAndValuesForTable> allVarsWithVals = new ArrayList<VarAndValuesForTable>();
        ArrayList<String> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        vals.add("ff");
        vals.add("kkk");
        vals.add("yyy");

        allVarsWithVals.add(new VarAndValuesForTable(1, "var 1", vals));
        allVarsWithVals.add(new VarAndValuesForTable(2, "var 2", vals));

        return allVarsWithVals;
    }
}
```

Here is controller's part:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    ArrayList<VarAndValuesForTable> projectVarWithVals = VarAndValuesForTable.getAllVarsNamesWithValues(FullWorkProject.currentLoadedProject);


    allVarsValsForTable = FXCollections.observableArrayList(projectVarWithVals);
    projectVarNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<VarAndValuesForTable, String>("varName"));
    varValuesColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<VarAndValuesForTable, String>("varValues"));
    varValuesColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(allVarsValsForTable));
    textVarsValsTable.setItems(allVarsValsForTable);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Although I can make out where the problem is but it would be great if you can provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This makes it easier for people to debug and offer a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have the wrong type for this column property. The `ComboBox` is the editing method. The value of the property (and therefore also the column) must be the underlying type. If you want multiple `String` values, you should have a `Property<String>` as the property.

Also note that there is no need for the data model (`VarAndValuesForTable` in your case) to hold the possibles values for the Combo Box - they are explicitly given in `ComboBoxTableCell#forTableColumn`. If you need different possible values for different rows you will have to create your own `ComboBoxTableCell` and populate each one with the relevant values.

Comment: thatnk you. Could you please advice some link to understand this descision? it is still very difficult for me